# Drupal: Include user profile data in page.tpl (phptemplate_preprocess_page?)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to pull user profile fields to display in my page.tpl.  I know the profile data isnt included in the $user array but I think with the theme function phptemplate_preprocess_page I can add the data, but Im not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
profile_load_profile($user);
```

Will add the profile data to the user object.